# Do I need an audio interface or is this good enough?

Tags: electric-guitar, sound

Honestly, I don't hear the difference. One of them is recorded with Behringer UMC22 and the other one is recorded with the Asus Z370-H motherboard's onboard sound card.

I have a powerful PC, I can choose any buffer size I want. (I guess the lowest is better, I use that)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16aDgmBU5rWIES-OOxFuEKPRKCyzuzLpg?usp=sharing

I'm not gonna tell which one is which one to see if you guys can tell the difference.

Disclaimer: I'm not very good at playing the guitar. I'm still learning. Just compare the sounds, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How necessary is a USB Audio Interface?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11167/how-necessary-is-a-usb-audio-interface)